# I am using qtip2 with jQuery validate, tooltip doesn't disappear after validating inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, qtip2, qtip

The tooltip is not getting disappeared after validating the input, it still shows.

My code is below, please help me out for finding how can I remove it after filling or validating my inputs.

```
$('#signupForm').validate({
            rules: {
              username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
              },
              phone:{
                tel: true,
                required: true
              },
              message: {
                required: true,
                minlength:2
              },
              email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
              },
              captcha: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
              }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    flipIt = $(element).parents('div.left').length > 0,
                    position = {
                        at: 'center center',
                        my: 'top top'
                    },
                    offset = flipIt ? 6 : 35;
                $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').qtip({ 
                    overwrite: false,
                    content: error,
                    position: position,
                    show: {
                        event: false,
                        ready: true
                    },
                    hide: false,
                    style: { 
                        classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow',
                        tip: {
                            corner: true,
                            offset: offset
                        }
                    }
                }).qtip('option', 'content.text', error);
            } ,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                  $(".contact-button").val("Please Wait...");
                  $(".contact-button").prop('disabled', true);
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/contact_page.php",
                    data: 'username='+$("#username").val()+'&email='+$("#email").val()+'&phone='+$("#phone").val()+'&message='+$("#message").val()+'&captcha='+$("#captcha").val(),
                    timeout: 3000,
                    success:function(data){
                      $("#mail-status").html(data);
                      $("#signupForm").find("input, textarea").val("");
                      $(".contact-button").val("Sent");
                      setTimeout(function () { 
                          $('#signupForm').find('.valid').qtip('destroy');
                      }, 1);
                      refreshCaptcha();
                      setTimeout(function() {
                      $(".contact-button").prop('disabled', false);
                      $("#mail-status").text("");
                      $(".contact-button").val('Click to Send'); 
                      }, 10000);
                    },
                    error: function() {alert('failed');}
                  });
            }
        });
```

In this whenever I try to fill inputs it shows the error message as tooltip but if I fill it right (valid) it still appear on 'tip'.
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently its

```
hide: false
```

change it to:

```
hide: { when: { event: 'mousemove' }, 
           delay: 2000, 
           effect: function() { $(this).qtip("destroy"); }
         }
```

Comment: It's working ...........but there is another problem occurs, it destroyed the tool-tip message but still shows the tip box ( empty box )

Comment: try by completely deleting hide property itself. Can you replicate in jsfiddle/jsbin and give

Comment: https://jsbin.com/saposudoqe/edit?html,css,js,console,output


Have a look on it !